# Php: what's the difference between while...endwhile; and while { // stuff here }

Tags: php

What's the difference between

```
while (expression):

// do stuff

endwhile;
```

and

```
while {

}
```

Comment: Alternate syntax can make it harder to edit because it doesn't afford brace matching in IDEs.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further?

Comment: further explanation: programming text editors will usually highlight the standard syntax braces '{...}' when your cursor is over either brace so it's easy to identify the statement blocks and control flow. The alternative syntax can be exasperating if there are a lot of nested control structures and poor indentation.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no functional difference.

In practical use I find that:

```
while (expression):
// do stuff
endwhile;
```

Is more readable for the designers when you are embedding php code within html. IE:

```
<? while ($cssClass = array_pop($array)): ?>
   <li class="<?=$cssClass?>">
<? endwhile; ?>
```

Whereas:

```
while {

}
```

Is more readable within a php code block.

Comment: You can even add pure html between the {} brackets like `while{ ?> your awsome html <?php } ...` **but** as already mentioned, **it's less readable**...

Answer (score 7):

There's no difference, it comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is negligible when the code is actually run, but when coding I find that typing the brackets is (1): quicker, (2): more conventional, and (3): allows for less chance of error (endwhle anyone?).

As a bonus, the editor I use auto-formats the while loops (with brackets, by default) and down the road, if anything is off, the built-in bracket-matching function will catch it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real difference when writing code.

There can be a difference in levels of convenience in very special circumstances. For example, suppose you are writing a template engine that converts template code to native PHP code which is then cached and executed directly for speed.

In this case, the fact that `while`...`endwhile;` avoids using braces may allow you to simplify your parsing algorithm if e.g. it recognizes variables that should be substituted with a syntax like `{$var}`, which also uses braces.

Of course this is a pretty small benefit in a really extraordinary situation, but you take what you can. :)